# What happens if thread that called "SELECT FOR UPDATE" dies? Is the row locked forever?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, locking, innodb, deadlock

I have a multi-threaded application that locks and unlock rows in one of my MYSQL table. As an example, all my threads that interact with this table call `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;` followed by `UPDATE ...` sometime later. I am worried what would happen if the thread that took the exclusive lock by calling `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` dies and never manages to call the `UPDATE ...` that would release the lock. Then would I have a deadlock? Is there a way to force the lock to be released if the thread who has the lock dies?

Comment: Eventually the database should detect the dead connection, probably via a read timeout, close the connection, and clean up. It's easy enough to test.

Answer (score 8):

The locks will automatically be released when the MySQL client <strike>process</strike> session terminates. (I'm referring to the session that MySQL has initiated and is maintaining on the MySQL server, the "sessions" reported by this MySQL statement:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

If the client app dies and leaves the MySQL client session alive on the server, the lock will continue to be held, until the client session thread terminates (due to an idle wait timeout,  or due to a MySQL `KILL` statement be executed.)

This wouldn't necessarily lead to a "deadlock" condition. (A deadlock is when MySQL determines that two or more <strike>process</strike> sessions are holding locks that are needed by the other <strike>process</strike> session; if it's just one <strike>process</strike> session  holding a lock, and that <strike>process</strike> session is **not** trying (i.e. waiting) to obtain a lock on a resource locked by another session, then it wouldn't lead to a "deadlock". Another <strike>process</strike> session trying to obtain a lock (on the same row/block) will just hang, waiting for the lock to be released.

It's not just a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` that can hold a lock; in the context of a transaction, any DML statement will hold locks until the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` happens.

---

I believe the default "timeout" for an idle session is 8 hours, specified as a value in seconds:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'
```

After a session has been idle for a period of `wait_timeout` seconds, MySQL will terminate the session, and any locks held by that session will be released.

Comment: @EJP: It would be better if I had said "session" or "connection". On Linux, MySQL is a single process, multiple threads. Each MySQL client connection (session) is a single thread in MySQL (at least up through MySQL 5.5 that's true). The identifier (`Id`) for the sessions can be obtained with the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` statement. The point is, a session will continue to hold any "locks" it has obtained until a COMMIT or ROLLBACK (either explicit or implicit)  as long as the session is "alive".